# How long did an angular httpClient request last?

Tags: angular, httpclient

Is there a way to know how long did an angular HttpClient request take to execute?

Comment: Using "Network" tab in developer tools?

Comment: I want to show on the app how long the request took.

Answer (score 1):

```
public myRequest(): Observable<any>{
    const startTime = performance.now();
    return http.post<any>(url).pipe(
        tap(x => { 
            const endTime = performance.now();
            console.log(`Took ${endTime - startTime} to complete.`);
        })
    )
}
```